# verify if an array is in ascending or descending order

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array which contains dates.

```
dates = [#<DateTime: 2002-07-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2452457j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<DateTime: 2003-10-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2452944j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<DateTime: 2003-12-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2452975j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<DateTime: 2004-03-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2453066j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<DateTime: 2004-03-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2453066j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

How can I check the sort order of this array if its ascending or descending?

Comment: Why not just compare the first two dates?

Comment: @AlexDev, first two dates might not be enough, especially if they are the same date, you might even have an array where all values are the same, so probably want to test them all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An array is ascending if the first of each two adjacent elements is less or equal than the second:

```
def ascending? arr
  arr.each_cons(2).all?{|left, right| left <= right}
end
```

alternatively (prettier but unfortunately slower), you can compare the array with sorted version of itself:

```
def ascending? arr
  arr == arr.sort
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Mladen, Here is what i did and its working great. assert_equal(dates,dates.sort!) to verify if its descending and assert_equal(dates,dates.sort) to make sure its ascending.

Comment: Be careful with `sort!` as it will modify your original array, not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Yes this exactly what I wanted. I'm basically using cucumber & webdriver to write some tests. When I click the Ascending link I want to make sure that the list displayed is in ascending order. So I capture the whole list of dates into an array and compare it with the sorted array for ascending and for descending I compare it with sort!

Comment: Could you please explain, which value is i and which is j in the comparison?

Comment: Thank you @MladenJablanović

Answer (score 6):

Here's some benchmark results for processing speed:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'date'

ary = (DateTime.parse('2002-07-01T00:00:00+00:00') .. DateTime.parse('2004-03-01T00:00:00+00:00')).to_a

def ascending1? arr
  arr.reduce{ |e1,e2| e1 <= e2 ? e2 : (return false) }; true
end

def ascending2? arr
  arr.each_cons(2).all?{|i,j| i <= j}
end

def ascending3? arr
  arr == arr.sort
end

n = 10_000
Benchmark.bm(9) do |b|
  b.report('reduce')    { n.times{ ascending1?(ary) } }
  b.report('each_cons') { n.times{ ascending2?(ary) } }
  b.report('sort')      { n.times{ ascending3?(ary) } }
end
```

With the test results:

```
                user     system      total        real
reduce      1.380000   0.000000   1.380000 (  1.381107)
each_cons   2.250000   0.000000   2.250000 (  2.243958)
sort        0.670000   0.000000   0.670000 (  0.675025)
```

---

Here's some 2020 results with `ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]`:

```
                user     system      total        real
reduce      0.765766   0.000939   0.766705 (  0.767853)
each_cons   1.220724   0.001394   1.222118 (  1.223502)
sort        0.693166   0.009011   0.702177 (  0.702492)
```

Comment: Update as of 2020: reduce is the fastest, sort the slowest. :)

Comment: I just ran the code to test, and it still returns the same order. All the routines are faster though.

Comment: Interesting, I'm consistently getting `reduce<each_cons<sort` with `ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 4):

Why not just check if the sorted array is the same as the unsorted array?

`array == array.sort` for ascending

and `array == array.sort.reverse` for descending

Comment: I was trying to use sort for this over here earlier today, and it doesn't necessarily work because Ruby's sort is not stable.

Answer (score 0):

I think `reduce` will be faster than `each_cons`

```
def ascending? arr
  arr.reduce{ |e1,e2| e1 <= e2 ? e2 : (return false) }; true
end
```

Comment: `all?` should return immediately as well.